# golang http server,can't get post value

Tags: http, go

```
func login(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    req.ParseForm()

    if req.Method == "GET" {
        fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Error Method")
    } else {
        name := strings.TrimSpace(req.FormValue("userid"))
        fmt.Println("userid:", name)
        fmt.Println("pwd:", req.FormValue("pwd"))
        fmt.Fprintf(rw, "welcome back,%s", req.FormValue("userid"))
    }
}
```

and i using ASIhttprequst send a from,like this.

```
[self setRequest:[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/login"]]];
[request setPostValue:@"userid" forKey:@"fdfs@jkjlf.cm"];
[request setPostValue:@"pwd" forKey:@"fdsfdsfdkskfjhds"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
```

i got a null value with req.FormValue("userid")

what happend? and how to fix it?

Comment: just a shot in the dark - maybe you just mixed up PostValue and PostKey?

Comment: dump the HTTP request

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

```
req.ParseForm()
req.Form.Get(key)
```

Comment: Yes, but you must precede that with `req.ParseForm()`.

Comment: Dont know why your answer wasn't accepted. Straight and to the point

Answer (score 4):

did you already test it with `req.PostFormValue` instead of `req.FormValue` ?

Comment: yes,i try PostFormValue instead of FormValue,but the result is still the same.

Comment: did you also test it with `req.ParseMultipartForm()` instead of `req.ParseForm()`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution with calling `ParseMultipartForm` before `ParseForm`, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you make multipart/form-data POST request, ParseForm does not parse request body correctly (this might be a bug). So, use ParseMultipartForm if that is the case.

Or you can call FormValue or PostFormValue directly without calling these parse methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues using ParseForm. I ended up doing something like this:

```
type UserRequest struct {
  UserId  string `json:"userid"`
  Pwd     string `json:"pwd"`
}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   var ur UserRequest
   decode := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
   decoder.Decode(&ur)

   // Access data via struct
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To extract a value from a post request you have to call `r.ParseForm()` at first. [This](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) parses the raw query from the URL and updates r.Form.

> For POST or PUT requests, it also parses the request body as a form
>   and put the results into both r.PostForm and r.Form. POST and PUT body
>   parameters take precedence over URL query string values in r.Form.

Now your `r.From` is a map of all values your client provided. To extract a particular value you can use `r.FormValue("<your param name>")` or `r.Form.Get("<your param name>")`.

So basically you will have this:

```
r.ParseForm()
res := r.FormValue("<your param name>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Form contains the parsed form data, including both the URL
    // field's query parameters and the POST or PUT form data.
    // **This field is only available after ParseForm is called.**
    // The HTTP client ignores Form and uses Body instead.
    Form url.Values

    // PostForm contains the parsed form data from POST, PATCH,
    // or PUT body parameters.
    //
    // **This field is only available after ParseForm is called.**
    // The HTTP client ignores PostForm and uses Body instead.
    PostForm url.Values
```

Comment: This field is only available after ParseForm is called.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **req.Body** `io.Reader` buffer is getting cleared by reading it in some level

ex: `ioutil.ReadAll` if Body buffer got cleared it will return empty value on `FormValue` even you `ParseForm`

Answer (score -1):

Try this buddy.

hope it will work as it works for me

```
r.FormValue("userid")
```